# How to create a custom grouped view in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the sample df below:

```
Project Name    Industry    Due Date
P - ABC         FI          1/31/2020
P - POA         FI          1/8/2020
P - BCD         MANU        1/25/2020
P - QWE         RES         3/6/2020
P - POI         FI          6/7/2020
P - RLK         TECH        6/9/2020
P - MJK         RET         3/18/2020
P - KIU         TECH        4/19/2020
P - KNJ         RES         3/9/2020
P - ISA         TECH        4/3/2020
P - YUI         FI          4/2/2020
```

I want to create a grouped view as below and I tried pandas pivot table but didn't meet my expectation and returns error...

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Industry'],columns=['Due Date'],values=['Project Name'])
```

Expected outputs:

```
                 Jan       Mar       Apr       Jun
Industry
FI              P - POA             P - YUI    P - POI
                P - ABC
MANU            P - BCD
RES                        P - QWE
                           P - KNJ
RET                        P - MJK
TECH                                P - ISA    P - RLK
                                    P - KIU
```

Does anyone have any thoughts? Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Can you also show what results and error you are getting ?

Comment: Do you plan to *do anything* with this view, or is this only for visualization? That Index is not something you can easily create with `pandas` and it would be a pain to work with afterwards.

Comment: Replied to @ALollz: I just want to have the expected output for visualization only. But I don't know how to achieve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below:

```
m= (df[['Industry','Project Name']]
    .assign(Month=pd.to_datetime(df['Due Date']).dt.month_name()))

idx=m['Industry'].unique()
final = (m.pivot_table('Project Name',
      ['Industry',m.groupby(['Industry','Month']).cumcount()],
       'Month',aggfunc='first',fill_value='')
       .rename_axis(None,axis=1).reindex(idx,level=0))
```

---

```
print(final)

             April  January     June    March
Industry                                      
FI       0  P - YUI  P - ABC  P - POI         
         1           P - POA                  
MANU     0           P - BCD                  
RES      0                             P - QWE
         1                             P - KNJ
TECH     0  P - KIU           P - RLK         
         1  P - ISA                           
RET      0                             P - MJK
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using `.groupby`, which is more of a pipeline approach rather than using `pivot_table`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("P - ABC","FI","1/31/2020"),
        ("P - POA","FI","1/8/2020"),
        ("P - BCD","MANU","1/25/2020"),
        ("P - QWE","RES","3/6/2020"),
        ("P - POI","FI","6/7/2020"),
        ("P - RLK","TECH","6/9/2020"),
        ("P - MJK","RET","3/18/2020"),
        ("P - KIU","TECH","4/19/2020"),
        ("P - KNJ","RES","3/9/2020"),
        ("P - ISA","TECH","4/3/2020"),
        ("P - YUI","FI","4/2/2020"),
    ],
    columns=("Project Name","Industry","Due Date")
)
# I've wrapped the Pandas pipeline in parentheses to allow for line breaks
(
    df
    .set_index(pd.to_datetime(df["Due Date"]).dt.month_name())
    .pipe(lambda x: x.groupby([x["Industry"], x.index]))
    .max()  # This technically works but there might be better opts
    .unstack()
    ["Project Name"]
)

Out[]: 
Due Date    April  January     June    March
Industry
FI        P - YUI  P - POA  P - POI      NaN
MANU          NaN  P - BCD      NaN      NaN
RES           NaN      NaN      NaN  P - QWE
RET           NaN      NaN      NaN  P - MJK
TECH      P - KIU      NaN  P - RLK      NaN
```